# I lost the key I signed my Android application with

Tags: android

I lost the .keys.ks file, that I used to sign my Android (on the Market) app. Is there anything I could do? I really hope I won't have to republish the app with a different package name on the Market, because current users won't see my updates. If I recreate it in Eclipse with the same password can I create the same key?

Answer (score 9):

No, there is nothing you can do. You have to sign with a new key. And no, current users will not see your updates, and if it is a paid application, they also will have to pay again to install the application.

Always backup your key. I have it in my gmail, and also on my skydrive, just in case.

Comment: It's not possible to recreate the key if I remember the password?

Comment: You could try recreating it. Then upload an update to the market. if it takes it, then it works.

Comment: @fhucho No, using the same password will not generate the same key.

Comment: That sucks... iPhone devs can request the key from Apple.

Comment: Thank God, I found a copy of my keystore in my Windows partition :-)

Comment: That's great. make sure you email it to a gmail account and/or store it on a cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Adroid Studio then do this.

1st try to create new keystore.

then open taskArtifacts.bin with notepad which located in ....gradle\2.14.1\taskArtifacts\taskArtifacts.bin and look for password that you just given or id.

Copy near by words and paste in search box...and search.

It will show whatever password you given to app.Even you will get id.